# Get max and count in same query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to validate data before performing an export.  Most people would validate the data first, before it's added to the collection, but in this case it can't be done because someone needs to assign net and team AFTER the people register.  SO, what I'm trying to do is check for missing net#s in the sequence.  It should go net 1, 2, 3, etc.  I thought I could group by event, and net and use $max to get the highest net assigned for that event.  Then, I could compare the number of unique nets with the $max number.  If they are equal, we are good.  I can't figure out how to make the query correctly.  $max always comes out null or doesn't show up.

sample data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591c7e1710c42a02a1833fef"), "event" : "Junior Girls 16s", "field" : "Main", "day" : "Friday", "division" : "Junior Girls", "level" : "16s", "group" : "nonpro", "numplayers" : 2, "price" : 50, "net" : 1, "team" : 1 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591c7e1710c42a02a1833fef"), "event" : "Junior Girls 16s", "field" : "Main", "day" : "Friday", "division" : "Junior Girls", "level" : "16s", "group" : "nonpro", "numplayers" : 2, "price" : 50, "net" : 1, "team" : 2 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591c7e1710c42a02a1833fef"), "event" : "Junior Girls 16s", "field" : "Main", "day" : "Friday", "division" : "Junior Girls", "level" : "16s", "group" : "nonpro", "numplayers" : 2, "price" : 50, "net" : 1, "team" : 3 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591c7e1710c42a02a1833fef"), "event" : "Junior Girls 16s", "field" : "Main", "day" : "Friday", "division" : "Junior Girls", "level" : "16s", "group" : "nonpro", "numplayers" : 2, "price" : 50, "net" : 1, "team" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591e07186f335b497bef0f9a"), "event" : "Junior Girls 16s", "field" : "Main", "day" : "Friday", "division" : "Junior Girls", "level" : "16s", "group" : "nonpro", "numplayers" : 2, "price" : 50, "net" : 3, "team" : 1 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591e07186f335b497bef0f9a"), "event" : "Junior Girls 16s", "field" : "Main", "day" : "Friday", "division" : "Junior Girls", "level" : "16s", "group" : "nonpro", "numplayers" : 2, "price" : 50, "net" : 3, "team" : 2 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591e07186f335b497bef0f9a"), "event" : "Junior Girls 16s", "field" : "Main", "day" : "Friday", "division" : "Junior Girls", "level" : "16s", "group" : "nonpro", "numplayers" : 2, "price" : 50, "net" : 3, "team" : 3 }
```

How I'd like the data to display:

```
event                maxNet      count (count of unique event/net field combo)    
Junior Girls 16s     3           2
```

One of the many things I've tried:

```
db.registrations.aggregate([
            {$match: {event: "Juniors Girls 16s"}},
            {$group: {_id: {event: "$event", net: "$net"}, count: {$sum:1}}},
            { $project: {event: "$event", count: {$sum: 1}, maxNet: {$max: "$_id.net"}}}
        ]);
```

Can someone please help me understand how I can fix this to work?

Comment: You should add your own answer here that you came to and mentioned in the comments. It is the only correct answer here afterall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with the help of you wonderful contributors above, I was able to make it work with:

```
db.registrations.aggregate([          
     { "$match": searchParams },                
     { "$group": { "_id": { "event": "$event" },                         
                "netCount": {$addToSet: "$net"},                          
                "maxNet":{$max: "$net"}      }},
    {$project: {nets: {$size: "$netCount"},maxNet: "$maxNet"}}, 
    {$match: {nets: {$ne: "$maxNet"} }}       
])
```

This gives me the event, the number of unique net numbers used, and the highest net number used for that event.  I was trying to use the final line: `{$match: {nets: {$ne: "$maxNet"}}}` to only display events where those numbers are not the same (either we skipped a net number, or used the same one on two different fields).  Not sure what I did to make that part not work, but it displays the results I wanted in the cleanest fashion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this will give you what you are looking for:

```
db.registrations.aggregate([
    {$match: {event: 'Junior Girls 16s'}}, 
    {$group: {_id: {event: "$event", net: "$net"}, count: {$sum:1}}}, 
    {$project: {event: "$_id.event", count: "$count", maxNet: {$max: "$_id.net"}}}
]);
```

Comment: This is close, but isn't filtering quite right.  I learned that net should not be in the grouping.  I should use addToSet to get the number of unique nets used, and $max to get the highest net number used.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks for help doing just that!  Sometimes we need feedback from others to come to a solution.